# PowerShell foreach() multidimensional array based on first element

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I have a fairly basic multidimensional array which looks something like this:

```
2017,123 
2017,25
2018,5
2018,60
2017,11
```

I wish to run a ForEach() loop or similar function to total the numbers in the second element based on the year indicated in the first so that I end up with an output like this:

```
2017,159
2018,65
```

How do I best accomplish this?

Comment: Please show us the code with which you define the array and assign the values. Answer may differ based on whether it's an actual multidimensional array, a jagged/nested array or a flat array of objects

Comment: It is a pretty basic array. It is populated within a loop and looks something like this:
    $myArray += ,($year, $amount)

Comment: Create a hashtable?

Comment: I've been trying, but my PS skills clearly aren't there yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is *concise*, but *not fast*:

```
# input array
$arr = 
  (2017,123),
  (2017,25),
  (2018,5),
  (2018,60),
  (2017,11)

# Group the sub-arrays by their 1st element and sum all 2nd elements
# in each resulting group.
$arr | Group-Object -Property { $_[0] } | ForEach-Object {
  , ($_.Name, (($_.Group | ForEach-Object { $_[1] } | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum))
}
```

Comment: @BjørnH.Sandvik: My pleasure; glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array looks like "$array" this will give you what you need:

```
$2017total = 0
$2018total = 0

$array = "2017,123",
"2017,25",
"2018,5",
"2018,60",
"2017,11" | % { 

if ($_ -match '2017') {
    $2017 = ($_ -split ',')[1]
    $2017total += $2017
}
else {
    $2018 = ($_ -split ',')[1]
    $2018total += $2018
} 
}

Write-Host "2017,$2017total"
Write-Host "2018,$2018total"
```

Comment: I very much appreciate the approach, but the array may contain any number of different years in the first element. I am looking for a way to handle this variety dynamically..

Comment: In SQL-speak, what I am looking for is akin to SELECT SUM(COLUMN2) GROUP BY COLUMN1 ORDER BY COLUMN1